# Defining an alert view and using it

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview

I've defined an alert view in my .h file (@property...), and in my .m file (@synthesize...) so that I can refer to it in multiple methods. When I have an alert view alloc, how do I tell it that this is the alert view that I've defined in the h and m files?

Comment: do you mean how do you assign it to the property you declared in the header? Or do you mean how do I test a UIAlertView to determine if it is the same as the one I have already set to the property declared in the header?

Comment: I want to to call a method to bring up this alert view that I defined in the h and m file and then later, in a DIFFERENT method, dismiss it. If I talk about the alert view in one method, the other method will have no idea what I'm talking about. So I defined the alert view in the h and m files as alertViewLoading. So I want to, in one method, alloc alertViewLoading. But how would I do that? And then in another method, release it, which would be [alertViewLoading release];. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it a *subclass* of `UIAlertView` you've defined, or is it just a property of type `UIAlertView *`?

Comment: Okay I think I follow.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is assign your alert view to the property you setup just like you would anything else.  Like here, where myAlertProperty is the property you setup in your interface and implementation:

```
UIAlertView *newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SomeTitle" message:@"SomeMessage" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
self.myAlertProperty = newAlert;
[newAlert show];
[newAlert release];
```

It's okay (and best) to release here since you are assigning it to a property (assuming you have `retain` in your @property).  When you handle the dismiss you can just say:

```
self.myAlertProperty = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Assuming you have defined your alert view in a separate alert class:

```
- (void)addToView:(UIView *)view
    // Adds itself as a subview to the specified view.
{
    [self addToView:view animated:NO];
}
```

In ViewController A, you call the alert class to add the alert to the current view.

```
[self.alertView addToView:parentViewController.view];
```

Then in View B, you call the alert class remove it from superview:

```
[self.alertView removeFromSuperviewAnimated:YES];
```

Make sure you are importing the alert class in both ViewController A and ViewController B

Comment: Do you mean addSubview and removeFromSuperView?

Comment: This isn't how you use `UIAlertView`--it appears modally, never as a subview of another view.

Comment: I did not call UIAlertView. I have a subview that is similar in appearance to UIAlertView that allows me to do other things (i.e. activity indicator), which I happen to call "alertView" for the purpose of this example. Maybe there are better ways, but thought I'd offer a suggestion. What I list above works for me.